# How can I disable bookmarking in chrome on a mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

When using chrome on a Mac, command+D creates a bookmark.
Winkey+D in windows minimizes all windows.
These are, unfortunately, the same keys.

Since I swap daily between Mac and Windows, I keep accidentally bookmarking pages. Is there any way to disable this shortcut in chrome/mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *System Preferences » Keyboard » Shortcuts* and add a different shortcut for the menu entry.

Note that you have to enter *Bookmark This Tab…* for the menu entry (you can copy-paste it from the answer), or use the respective translated string.

[image]